# Retornar Ids buscando pelo valor de um array multidimensional

Tags: php, array

Existe alguma forma **sem utilizar foreach**, utilizando apenas funçoes nativas do PHP para retornar um array com os ids buscando todos que estao com o value 'a' ?

Exemplo:

```
$lista = array(
    array(
        'id' => '100',
        'name' => 'Sandra Shush',
        'value' => 'a'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => '5465',
        'name' => 'Stefanie Mcmohn',
        'value' => 'a'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => '40489',
        'name' => 'Michael',
        'value' => 'b'
    )
);
```

Retornar um array com os ids que tem o value 'a'

```
$lista_ids = array(100,5465);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não vejo porque não usar o foreach, pois quando se trata de arrays com índice ele é uma mão na roda. Foreach é [nativo](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php) do PHP.

Mas vamos ao que interessa:

```
<?php

$lista = array(
    array(
        'id' => '100',
        'name' => 'Sandra Shush',
        'value' => 'a'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => '5465',
        'name' => 'Stefanie Mcmohn',
        'value' => 'a'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => '40489',
        'name' => 'Michael',
        'value' => 'b'
    )
);
$ids = [];
for($i = 0; $i < count($lista); $i++) {
    if( $lista[$i]['value'] == 'a' ) {
        $ids[] = $lista[$i]['id'];
    }
}

var_dump($ids);
```

Simplificando a sintaxe de array, e fazendo com o foreach:

```
<?php

$lista = [
    [
        'id' => '100',
        'name' => 'Sandra Shush',
        'value' => 'a'
    ],
    [
        'id' => '5465',
        'name' => 'Stefanie Mcmohn',
        'value' => 'a'
    ],
    [
        'id' => '40489',
        'name' => 'Michael',
        'value' => 'b'
    ]
];
$ids = [];
foreach($lista as $item) {
    if ( $item['value'] == 'a' ) {
        $ids[] = $item['id'];
    }
}
var_dump($ids);
```

Você também pode fazer com o [array_map](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-map.php) dessa forma:

```
<?php
function teste($item) {
    if($item['value'] == 'a') {
        return $item['id'];
    }
}

$lista = [
    [
        'id' => '100',
        'name' => 'Sandra Shush',
        'value' => 'a'
    ],
    [
        'id' => '5465',
        'name' => 'Stefanie Mcmohn',
        'value' => 'a'
    ],
    [
        'id' => '40489',
        'name' => 'Michael',
        'value' => 'b'
    ]
];
$b = array_map("teste", $lista);
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($b);
echo '</pre>';
```

O array_map ele vai deixar null os que não entrarem na condição.

Comment: Obrigado, a ideia de nao precisar usar o foreach era no caso de já existir algo que eu escrevesse menos sem precisar fazer um loop.

Comment: Mas a ideia dos laços de repetições é exatamente essa.